# Apps script open html form from another html form by button

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I need help!

I need open html form from another html form by button PUTAWAY START.
At html code I have this button, but I cant understand how to write script to command for button.

I don't know where to start. Thank you for help!

```html
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1" style="width: 100%">PUTAWAY START</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

I know that it must be by function doGet(e) but how?

Thanks to help from Ron I add his script to my project.

Main form:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>KOP@CK-M@IN-MENU</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
            rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" 
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <?!= include("main-css"); ?>
  </head>
  
  <body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
        <link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/14GrCbJYe3RExAKL_6yuF3kH1EO0L7zge/view?usp=sharing" />
              <h6 style="color:blue;"><em>KOP@CK M@IN MENU:</em></h6>
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=14GDoNMZxgHlfTKMHmtamXmu93y2jaDy6" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
              <form>
                  <hr></hr>         
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="PUT@WAY ST@RT" style="width: 100%" onclick="Link1()"/>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="progress" id="PreLoaderBar">
                    <div class="indeterminate"></div>
                  </div>
                  <hr></hr> 
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2" style="width: 100%">Insert</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <hr></hr> 
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn3" style="width: 100%">Insert</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <hr></hr> 
              </form>
          </div>
          
      </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <?var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?><input type="hidden" value="<?= url ?>" id="url" />
  <?!= include("main-js"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and script in include-main:

```js
    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (document.readyState === "complete") {
                document.getElementById("PreLoaderBar").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

    function Link1(){
      var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
      console.log(url);
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      console.log(link);
      link.href = url + "&page=Link1";
      link.id = 'linkURL';
      console.log(link);
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      document.getElementById('linkURL').click();
    }
```

Script in "doGet":

```js
function doGet(e){
 var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  console.log(params);
  console.log(e.parameter.page);
  if(!e.parameter.page){
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("MAIN_MENU").evaluate();
  }
  else if(e.parameter.page == 'Link1'){
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("PUTAWAY_TO").evaluate();
  }
  else if(e.parameter.page == 'Main'){
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("MAIN_MENU").evaluate();
  }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear if your 'html form' is within a google product (doc, sheet, form) or just a website.  You also don't mention if you want to open another google product or a regular website.   Do you just need to open a link, or do you need to process a form then open another form?  If it is the second one, you will need at least a client side function and a server side function.   Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry for bad description. Both htmls exist in google sheet project and uploaded like web app. It's interesting is there an option to have html form like separate website but it will work with google sheet table? If it is possible what I must to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the doGet(e) [event parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters) as your condition to determine which html form you will create

### Sample Code:

Code.gs

```
function doGet(e){
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  Logger.log(params);
  Logger.log(e.parameter.page);
  if(!e.parameter.page){
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Main").evaluate();
  }
  else if(e.parameter.page == 'Link1'){
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Form1").evaluate();
  }
  else if(e.parameter.page == 'Main'){
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Main").evaluate();
  }
  
}
```

Main.html

```
 <body>
    <h1>Welcome to Main Form</h1>
    <?var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?><input type="hidden" value="<?= url ?>" id="url" />
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Link 1" onclick="link1()" />
  </body>
  <script>
    function link1()
    {
      var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url+"?page=Link1";
      link.id = 'linkURL';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      document.getElementById("linkURL").click();   
    }
  </script>
```

Form1.html

```
 <body>
    <h1>Welcome to Form 1</h1>
    <?var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?><input type="hidden" value="<?= url ?>" id="url" />
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Back to Main" onclick="main()" />
  </body>
  <script>
  function main()
  {
    var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url+"?page=Main";
      link.id = 'linkURL';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      document.getElementById("linkURL").click(); 
  }
  </script>
```

### What it does?

1. Creates a href link in your html page, the href link contains an event parameter "page". `link.href = url+"?page=Link1";`
2. When `doGet(e)` was called, It will check the `page` parameter in the `event object`. Then select the form you want to use based on the page parameter provided.

### Additional References:

- [Create Views (Pages) in Web App - Google Apps Script Web App Tutorial - Part 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7cO8ZyRCk4)
- [Link HTML Pages using Google Apps Script Web App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4STM4Cpr_w)

Comment: Thank you, I tried go this way, I found that idea in Youtube, but something didn't work. I will check and try again. Console log said the mistake in <?var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?><input type="hidden" value="<?= url ?>" id="url" />

Comment: Another question to script here. May be we can union first and third conditions in function doGet to one condition? They are about the same html

Comment: I tried your script in my project but I get "userCodeAppPanel:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Link1 is not defined"...

Comment: I edited code to this but on Loading but I'v got a message on the page "Couldn't open the file. Check that the address is correct and try again."  It seems like the link doesn;t work...

Comment: Hi, I just provided a simple example on how to open different forms you can optimize the code based on your preference as what you mentioned in combining conditions in the doGet(). I tried the answer provided before posting it and it is working on my end. You can update your question and provide your complete code so that we could help you in debugging your issue.

Comment: I made edits, inserted script on top of theme))

Comment: Your Link1() definition in the main form is missing?

Comment: your link.href is incorrect `link.href = url + "&page=Link1";` it should include "?" after the url and then followed by your first parameter. You just use "&" if you need to include additional parameter in your url. it should be `link.href = url + "?page=Link1`

Comment: thanks, I didn't notice it at all. After edit I have mistake 404 and "Couldn't open the file. Check that the address is correct and try again." - on top

Comment: Is your code already working? or did you encountered another issue?

Comment: yes, I get another issue, after edit to this "link.href = url + "?page=Link1" I get mistake 404 in Console log  and "Couldn't open the file. Check that the address is correct and try again."

Comment: I found my mistake, forgot one token here at the end of text link.href = url + "?page=Link1

Comment: Glad to hear that. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: at now I have another issue. [Intervention] Slow network is detected. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5636954674692096 for more details. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/productsans/v12/pxiDypQkot1TnFhsFMOfGShVF9eO.woff2May be it's because my connection goes through wi-fi, a little later I will test again)

Comment: the check button under the upvote and downvote is not available?

Comment: regarding your another issue, I'm sorry but it is out of our scope of expertise. We only support questions related to our product

Comment: the check button is unvisible for me

Comment: I will test another issue a little later, when come home

Comment: I tested last problem, mistake with connection dissapeared. But this mistake exists - "Couldn't open the file. Check that the address is correct and try again." - and new html doesn't open

Comment: are you still trying to go to your Link1 page?

Comment: I used your code (replacing it with "link.href = url + "?page=Link1" ). It is working successfully from my side. (I just used some of my old html and renamed it to PUTAWAY_TO.html)

Comment: It's strange thing, may be that depends of our corporate accaunts?

Comment: When you fix your html file. Did you re-deploy your app? Under manage deployments -> edit your active deployment -> Select new version under Version tab

Comment: Of course I choose new version of app, when doing this)

Comment: Can you post the web browser link opened after you clicked your putaway_to button here? (redact some part of the link) example: https://script.google.com/a/macros/google.com/s/....../exec?page=Link1

Comment: Yes, sure. This link I get when I build web-app https://script.google.com/a/fmlogistic.com/macros/s/AKfycbxL8UvPytXA2u9i78C-LX-o_5zLsz4EkC3AWmRwotrD/dev     and this link I get when click button https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw60bZu-BQ0kJ7NMkohJwZLGFHIN0cf5-Dkz-lq-Qeh9pkuDNaL/exec?page%20=%20Link1

Comment: It seems that the problem is this part ?page%20=%20Link1, your request url should be ?page=Link1. If you manually append that in your main url, it should open up your putaway form. %20 represents spaces. I think you append your url like this ?page = Link1. Please remove the spaces in between

Comment: I made that but it did not help. Link is https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxL8UvPytXA2u9i78C-LX-o_5zLsz4EkC3AWmRwotrD/dev?page=Link1 and error message is the same

Comment: could you check your link I again. your link provided last april 2 is this https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw60bZu-BQ0kJ7NMkohJwZLGFHIN0cf5-Dkz-lq-Qeh9pkuDNaL/exec?page%20=%20Link1 while yesterday it is now https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxL8UvPytXA2u9i78C-LX-o_5zLsz4EkC3AWmRwotrD/dev?page=Link1. Your latest link has "/dev" instead of "/exec?"

Comment: I do not know what is the difference between these links. Can you explain me this? I found cause of mistake on top. i needed to grant permissions and html PUTAWAY_TO opened)) thank you for help!